# #WPF Datagrid a txt

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Al escribir los datos del dataGrid en un archivo de texto solo me muestra App.persona.Persona, ¿por qué?. Gracias.

//Guardar datos.

```
    private void Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog datos = new SaveFileDialog();
        datos.Filter = "Texto(*.txt) | *.txt";

        if (datos.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string archivo = datos.FileName;
            StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < DataGridNames.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Persona line = (Persona)DataGridNames.Items[i];
                strB.AppendLine(line.ToString());
            }
            File.WriteAllText(archivo, strB.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sobreescribe el método ToString() en la clase Persona para que muestre lo que tu quieres..

Comment: Sí, eso hice. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas en la siguiente sentencia:

```
strB.AppendLine(line.ToString());
```

Donde `line` es de tipo `Persona` por el casteo en la línea anterior.
Al hacer `line.ToString()` estás llamando al método heredado de **object** `ToString()` que si no lo sobrecargaste en tu clase `Persona` entonces -por defecto- mostrará lo que indicas `App.persona.Persona` (Namespace.Clase).
Lo que puedes hacer es sobrecargar el método que te indiqué o realizar algo similar a:

```
strB.AppendLine(${line.Propiedad1} {line.OtraPropiedad} {line.MiPropiedad});
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo puedo sobrecargar el método? porque la otra opción no consigo que funcione.